# Writing audio to server over TCP socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, stream

I'm trying to transmit real time mic recording to server over TCP socket and server to write input stream to a file.
The connection is established but after some time, I'm getting connection refused error at my clientside.

Server Code:

```
    public class auServer extends Thread{
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static int port = 3333; 

    public void run()
    {

        System.out.println("init success");
       while(true)
       {

          try
          {
              serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
              serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
              Socket clientSoc = serverSocket.accept();
             System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
             System.out.println("Just connected to " + clientSoc.getRemoteSocketAddress());
             InputStream in = clientSoc.getInputStream();
             while(in!=null)
             {
                 writeToFile(in);
             }
             System.out.println("socket");

             clientSoc.close();
          }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
          {
             System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
             break;
          }catch(IOException e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
                     System.out.println("some io");
             break;
          } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("some e");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
    }

    private void writeToFile(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        // Write the output audio in byte
        String filePath = "8k16bitMono1.wav";
        short sData[] = new short[1024];
        byte[] bData = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
        FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
         os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
         System.out.println("Short wirting to file" + sData.toString());
         try {
          os.write(bData, 0, 2048);
         } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
        try {
         os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try
      {
        Thread serverThread = new auServer();
        serverThread.run();
        System.out.println("runing");
       }catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

and Client :

```
private void streamData(byte[] bData) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {  //bData is byte array to transmit
    Thread.sleep(500);
    Socket client = new Socket("10.221.40.41",3333);
    OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
    outToServer.write(bData);
    if(!isRecording)
        client.close();
}
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a foreground task?

Comment: Any exceptions? Please go through some "blocking Network I/O tutorial". There are multiple issues with the code.

Comment: "trying to transmit **real time** mic recording" - what is your definition of "real time"?

Comment: @Vyacheslav: The client part method is called from thread.

Comment: @Fildor: Kindly suggest some tutorial and please comment the issues. Real-time meaning, i'm recording over mic and recorded chunk I want to transmit simultaneously

Comment: @unknown , i mean your device can suddenly sleep if your screen is off.

Comment: @Vyacheslav this part I'm going to port to service, for now this is not an issue, its network errors :( This is just a part of an app and now I'm learning it now.

Comment: @Fildor the code is running ok for some span and after it gives Connection refused exception.

Comment: 'streamData(byte[] bData)' How many bytes in bData? Are you speaking about one call of streamData()?

Comment: @greenapps: no streamData()  is called in while loop for every recorded chunk of data i. e. bData that of 2048 bytes.

Comment: Why do you create a new client for every piece of data? And why does the server write those pieces to the same file again and again? The file will not grow but contain only one piece. Please explain what you have in mind.

Comment: `os.write(bData, 0, 2048);`. 2048 ? Are you sure? Why?

Comment: yes the size is 2048 as the size of bData was 2048. And the idea is like: while recording audio using mic, send it to server and write(append) an audio file at server.

Comment: You are not seriously answering my questions.

Comment: @greenapps the above code is working for recording and while debugging the value I observed was 2048 and hence I set it as a size

Comment: Post a stack trace and more of the client code. If you get "Connection refused" after some time has passed, it would be helpful to see what your client is doing over time.

Comment: @unknown The correct count for a write is the count you read in each specific case, not something you observe during debugging. The above code certainly does not work.

Comment: @EJP yes, that might be the case, but the problem (as asked in question) was connection refuse and I dont think buffer size will affect receiving packet of any size sent by client to server as long as both, sender and receiver, have same size. PS. I might be wrong, please correct me

Comment: Just a note, if you ever want a Code Review on your code (once it's working), head over to [codereview.se]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll comment on your code piece by piece.

```
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
```

There's no reason for this to be static.

```
while(true)
{
    try
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
```

The last two lines should be ahead of the loop. This is the reason for the connection refusals, and it will also cause `BindExceptions` that you haven't mentioned. It isn't clear why you need the timeout.

```
             Socket clientSoc = serverSocket.accept();
             System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
```

No you aren't. He's already connected. You were waiting *before* the `accept().`

```
             System.out.println("Just connected to " + clientSoc.getRemoteSocketAddress());
             InputStream in = clientSoc.getInputStream();
             while(in!=null)
```

Both the loop and the test are futile. The variable isn't null initially, and there is no way it can ever become null. The loop is futile because the `writeToFile()` method completely exhausts the input stream, so there is never anything more to read. This will be causing junk data, which you haven't mentioned.

```
             {
                 writeToFile(in);
             }
             System.out.println("socket");
```

A pointless message.

```
             clientSoc.close();
```

All the code from the line after `accept()` to here should be executed in a separate thread. The accept loop should do nothing but accept connections and start threads.

```
          }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
          {
             System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
```

What timed out here was the `accept()`, as the listening socket is the only socket you've set a timeout on. I doubt that you need this.

```
             break;
          }catch(IOException e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
                     System.out.println("some io");
```

Another futile message.

```
             break;
          } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("some e");
```

Yet another one. When you get an exception, *print the exception.* Not some futile message of your own devising. Otherwise debugging becomes a mere guessing game.

```
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
    }

    private void writeToFile(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        // Write the output audio in byte
        String filePath = "8k16bitMono1.wav";
        short sData[] = new short[1024];
```

Unused. Remove.

```
        byte[] bData = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
```

Don't use this. It wastes space and adds latency. See below for the correct solution.

```
        FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
         os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Poor technique. This `catch` is in the wrong place. Code that depends on the success of code in a `try` block should be inside the same `try` block. At present you are falling through this `try-catch` as though the exception never happened, which will cause a `NullPointerException` in the code below.

```
         System.out.println("Short wirting to file" + sData.toString());
```

Another pointless message. Misspelt; `sData` has nothing in it; `sData.toString()` doesn't print anything useful regardless of the contents; and incorrect, as you aren't writing `sData` at all.

```
         try {
          os.write(bData, 0, 2048);
```

This writes exactly 2048 bytes, regardless of the amount read, which could be less or more. If it was less it will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or similar, which I would expect to see on the second call, although you haven't mentioned it, because the array should be zero length on the second and subsequent calls, if any. It should be a loop, of the general form:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or more if you like
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Back to your code:

```
         } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
        try {
         os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try
      {
        Thread serverThread = new auServer();
        serverThread.run();
```

This runs the `run()` method of the thread. It doesn't start a thread. It should be `serverThread.start().`

```
        System.out.println("runing");
```

Misspelt. Until you fix the start/run problem above, you won't see this message until after the server's `run()` method  has exited.

> and Client :

```
private void streamData(byte[] bData) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {  //bData is byte array to transmit
    Thread.sleep(500);
```

Pointless. Remove. Don't put sleeps into networking code.

```
    Socket client = new Socket("10.221.40.41",3333);
```

Don't create a new connection per buffer. Use the same connection for the life of the client.

```
    OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
    outToServer.write(bData);
    if(!isRecording)
        client.close();
```

This should be unconditional, and it should be elsewhere, along with the creation of the socket.

> What could be the problem?

*Problems.* Plural. Multiple. See above.

Comment: Great explanation, this is what I was expecting, a REVIEW(+1). Thanks for efforts, will try with above guidelines and will mark as answer if it works. Thanks again and sorry for being rude :)

Comment: @EJP One thing at client side, if I do not new connection per buffer and close it in each loop, it's sending complete recording of 10XXX~ bytes (until i hit case of exiting while) at a same time. I want to send it as a 2048 bytes continuously(stream) and not at the end.

Comment: Streaming continuously is exactly what happens with the suggested changes. I don't understand what you mean by 'not at the end'.

Answer (score 3):

The creation of the serversocket must be done outside of the loop.
And for parallel connections you need to start a thread per connection.

Also apply the timeout to the established connections. A timeout on the serverSocket will end accepting after the timeout, this is nothing you want in a server.

```
...
public void run() {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("init success");

    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
            final Socket clientSoc = serverSocket.accept();
            clientSoc.setSoTimeout(10000);

            System.out.println("Just connected to " + clientSoc.getRemoteSocketAddress());


            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        InputStream in = clientSoc.getInputStream();
                        writeToFile(in);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            clientSoc.close();
                        } catch (Exception ignore) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing your client side is an android application. Once, I tried to read and write data to an android application through a socket connection. Eventually, I did it by using the adb(android debugger bridge).

Lets say, there is a java application which creates a `Socket` with the port number 1992. And there is an android application, which creates a `ServerSocket` with the port number 1993.

Here comes the real deal!

**Before you start running applications, you need to execute the following command in adb shell (or you can locate your adb in cmd/terminal and execute the command)**

```
adb forward tcp:1992 tcp:1993
```

After forwarding the port you can write and read data from java application to android application and wise-versa, using sockets' IO streams.

Desktop application code snippet :

```
while (flag) {
    try {
        final Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1992);
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {                        
                while (flag) {                            
                    try {
                        new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true).println(new Date().toString());
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }                    
        }.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // need port-forwarding
    }
}
```

Android application code snippet :

```
while (flag) {
    try {
        final Socket socket = new ServerSocket(1993).accept();
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                while (flag) {
                    try {
                        String line = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())).readLine();
                        Log.d("", line);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        break;
    }
}
```

You can convert your audio to byte array and write it into a output stream. Hope my answer will be useful.

Comment: Sorry for not neatly putting my question, My android app will stream audio to server. In my code, I'm transmitting byte data only and I couldn't get why `ADB forward tcp` is needed. Please explain.
Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution. 
The problem was actually with blocking Network I/O due to wrongly coded stream.

What I missed was

```
InputStream in = clientSoc.getInputStream();
DataInputStream DataIn =new DataInputStream(in)
while(DataIn!=null)
    {
        writeToFile(DataIn);
    }
```

and client side too

```
OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
out.write(sData);
```

Comment: No, you didn't figure out the solution. `while (DataIn != null)` doesn't begin to make sense. It can't be null, either initially or ever afterwards, so the loop will never terminate, and trying to write from the same stream more than once is futile,or should be. Changing to `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` is futile in this case as well. There are many problems with your code, but they are quite other than these.

Comment: @EJP I'm successful in getting packets for live stream and playing also them at server side. `DataIn!=null` may be a wrong condition,but when I added `DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);`, its working.
I agree code may have problems, but help me solving them instead of criticizing and making it -1.

Comment: You must have changed something else as well. That change changed nothing. `DataOutputStream.write()` and `DataInputStream.read()` are no different from any other read or write method. The code you posted here throws runtime exceptions. If you don't want your code criticized there is not much point in posting it. If it was perfect you wouldn't have a problem. You're jumping to conclusions all over the place. You have zero evidence about who downvoted your answer. You don't seem to understand how this site works, or code reviews either.

Comment: NB if you really think that the data input/output streams have the magical properties required to solve this problem, you need to say why, and what those properties are. Otherwise your answer just consists of cargo-cult programming.